# No session for PID xxx (lxpolkit)

Tags: debian, vnc, lxde

I'm trying to use `LXDE` on debian sid, launching it by adding `startlxde` to the end of `~/.vnc/xstartup`.

Using `tightvncserver` as VNC server:

```
tightvncserver -alwaysshared :1
```

However, when I log in from a VNC client, there is a warning saying:

> No session for PID xxx

(Where `xxx` is the PID for a process named `lxpolkit`)

Comment: I have something similar using Ubuntu server and lxde. Looking at my xstartup file I see that I had to change the lxde startup command. The 3 I tried was `startxfce4 &` `startlxde &` and `startlubuntu &` The `startlubuntu &` was the one that worked for me. Perhaps a starting place for you.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is still bugging us on Debian, on older versions Stretch and Buster only when calling `startx` from e.g. an SSH session to show up on the main console/screen (and I guess similarly on a VNC session), while on Debian Bullseye as well when starting LXDE directly from the local console.

This has been reported to the [Debian bug tracker](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=864402) as well.

A solution/workaround is to set the `polkit/command=` setting in `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/desktop.conf` empty, respectively remove `lxpolkit` from it. The same can be done via `lxsession-default-apps` package and command, respectively the entry in the settings menu, clearing the "Polkit agent" field.

While this mutes the prompt, I'm not sure about other, probably negative impacts. A deeper investigation is hence required.

Comment: Ah, this is great, because I just read in another answer how using lxpolkit in ldxe is the only way to be able to access Synaptic Package Manager from the menu. So, all I need to do, then, is remove lxpolkit, and make sure lxpolkit isn't removed, and everything ought to work. Sweet.

Comment: This makes sense, as Synaptic requires root privileges, which is what is granted via polkit. I did not have a look into this since a long time, but generally, if lxpolkit still causes problems, any other polkit agent should work, like `policykit-1-gnome` and using `polkit/command=/usr/lib/polkit-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1`.  A probably minimalist solution could be `pkexec` (since Debian Bookworm), which should be installed already, and hence `polkit/command=pkexec`.